# Weston + Qt5 Minimal-QML example

Tags: qt, wayland, qtwayland

I am trying to run one of [Qt5's Wayland Compositor examples](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtwaylandcompositor-examples.html). And I realize I still lack the concepts behind display server/client within the context of Wayland/Weston.

When I am running a Qt5 Compositor, I should have Weston already running at the backend as the display server, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No. Minimal-qml is a complete compositor, it doesn't need Weston.

Long Answer:

- `Wayland` is the protocol and IPC mechanism used by compositors and clients to talk to each other.
- `Weston` is the reference implementation of a compositor.
- `Qt Wayland` lets you develop your own compositor.

The binary produced by Qt Wayland can run wherever Qt applications can run, which means, you *could* actually run the compositor inside Weston, but It's not necessarily a good idea.

The most common use case is to run the Wayland compositor directly from a tty on the `eglfs` backend. I.e. run the compositor like this:

```
./minimal-qml -platform eglfs
```

Then launch client applications inside the compositor by running

```
./yourclient -platform wayland
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It helped a lot.

Comment: I was trying to figure out why my compositor kept complaining about an unset DISPLAY variable: it needed bsdfb or eglfs for the Qt Platform Plugin.